# Why does using document.write to create an iframe "cancel out" all remaining Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, behavior

This happens in all browsers, so there must be a reason.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>var a="support/";
var aa='<iframe src="http://google.com/' + a + '" />'; 
document.write(aa)</script> 
<script>alert('test')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code after the iframe write (in this case alert('test')) doesn't execute. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your HTML that you write into the document is invalid and causes the browser to fail interpreting the rest of the document, including the remaining `<script>` tags.

You are writing `<iframe src="http://google.com/support/`. Add `"></iframe>` and it's ok.

However, a cleaner approach would be not to use `document.write` at all (assuming you have some HTML element with id="container" to hold the iframe):

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://google.com/support/");
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(iframe);
```

Answer (score 9):

Because you're writing broken HTML into the document -- there's no > on the iframe tag.

Comment: Whoops, but even with the properly formatted HTMl, it still doesn't work. Edit: never mind, it does work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your quotes and iframe.  This works:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>var a="support/";
var aa='<iframe src="http://google.com/' + a + '" />';
document.write(aa)</script> 
<script>alert('test')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is Ok and working fine. You can check it on [**JSFiddle Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3fg10cnq/). Rest you can edit it with your data..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var write_variable="p/about.html";
var write_iframe='<iframe src="http://www.exeideas.com/' + write_variable + '" />';
document.write(write_iframe);
</script>
```

Or you can check it online via [**HTML Editor And Previewer**](http://newonlinetools.blogspot.com/2014/01/html-editor-and-previewer.html)